# keras predict_classes unexpected dim

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I'm just learning ML basics. I'm using keras/tensorflow (trough RStudio). I'm trying to develop a network to model the relationship between a 4 number vector which is related to an output of a 11 number vector. the values all are between 0-1. The sum of each vector has to be less than 1.
The model is

```
model_l1 <- keras_model_sequential()
model_l1 %>%
layer_dense(units = 64, activation = 'sigmoid', input_shape = c(4),dtype = 'float32') %>% 
layer_dropout(rate = 0.6) %>% 
layer_dense(units = 32, activation = 'sigmoid',dtype = 'float32') %>%
layer_dropout(rate = 0.4) %>%
layer_dense(units = 11, activation = 'sigmoid',dtype = 'float32')


model_l1 %>% compile(
loss = 'mean_squared_error',
optimizer = 'sgd',
metrics = c('mse','acc')
)
```

the training converges just fine with loss: 0.0037 - mean_squared_error: 0.0037 - acc: 0.9898.

If I use the testing set to evaluate the model:

```
model_l1 %>% evaluate(l_x_test, l_y_test)
```

I obtain this:

$loss
[1] 0.001548773

$mean_squared_error
[1] 0.001548773

$acc
[1] 0.9999

The problem is when I try to use the model to predict (by example using the same test set):

```
model_l1 %>% predict_classes((l_x_test)
```

I was expecting an 11 column output, but instead I obtain a vector with a constant number:

[1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5.....

I'm a little stuck here so I will appreciate any help
kind regards

PS:
The network was created using a web page sample, so I suppose my adaptation is not correct (please remember I'm just trying to learn the mechanics so I apologise in advance just in case)

Comment: `predict_classes` will return you the final predicted label, not probabilities. If you want the probability, you should probably use `predict_proba`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. predict_classes is simply the argmax of your output rather than the per-class probabilities. The non-argmaxed output can be obtained by predict (might be named predict_proba in the R wrapper).
2. If you want the output vectors probabilities to sum to one, use a softmax activation on your last layer.
3. None of what you have reported seems weird or wrong under the limited context you provided. Single-class predictions are justifiable in the case of heavy class imbalance, for instance.

Comment: Thank you!, that do it!.